# Can't setup mysql database for fabric-ca server due to certificate error

Tags: mysql, ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to setup Hyperledger fabric-ca using mysql database using this link: http://fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html

Following the content in the link, I am trying to setup fabric-ca-server with mysql as DB and I am specifying the below config for the same in the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

```
db:
  type: mysql
  datasource: root:rootpw@tcp(localhost:3306)/ca?parseTime=true&tls=custom
  tls:
      enabled: true
      certfiles:
        - server-cert.pem
      client:
        certfile: client-cert.pem
        keyfile: client-key.pem
```

I have used docker container to start mysql database using:

```
docker run --name=mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 mysql
```

After my container starts these logs are produced:

```
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1
[Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
[Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
[System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

And when I start my fabric-ca-server then these logs are produced:

```
[INFO] Configuration file location: /home/trinayan/Documents/biltinetwork/newca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
[INFO] Starting server in home directory: /home/trinayan/Documents/biltinetwork/newca
[WARNING] Unknown provider type: ; metrics disabled
[INFO] Server Version: 1.4.2
[INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:2 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
[WARNING] &{69 The specified CA certificate file /home/trinayan/Documents/biltinetwork/newca/ca-cert.pem does not exist}
[INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
[INFO] encoded CSR
[INFO] signed certificate with serial number 646347233835345802692423971159804543235939577965
[INFO] The CA key and certificate were generated for CA 
[INFO] The key was stored by BCCSP provider 'SW'
[INFO] The certificate is at: /home/trinayan/Documents/biltinetwork/newca/ca-cert.pem
[ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to connect to MySQL database: x509: certificate is valid for MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate, not localhost
[INFO] Home directory for default CA: /home/trinayan/Documents/biltinetwork/newca
[INFO] Operation Server Listening on [::]:36189
[INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054
```

I can't figure out why this error:

```
[ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to connect to MySQL database: x509: certificate is valid for MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate, not localhost
```

as this is related to ssl certificate so can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

From the error, I assume you are trying to connect to MySQL over TLS.
Looks like MySQL auto-generated a server certificate with a Common Name or SAN of `MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate`.
Likely in your config you are trying to connect to `localhost` which does not match `MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate`.

So you have a few options:

- follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files-using-mysql.html and generate certificates using openssl with the Common Name or a SAN set to `localhost`
- create a hosts entry on the host server running the CA and MySQL which maps `MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate` to `127.0.0.1` and replace `localhost` with `MySQL_Server_8.0.17_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate` in your fabric-ca-server config file.
- don't use TLS and see if things work

I'd go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks @Gari Singh for the answer. I will try the above options. And, yes I have already tried without using TLS and it works well in that case now I will check for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

So, since [it is not possible to set the Common Name of the certificates generated by mysql_ssl_rsa_setup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files-using-mysql.html)

A solution when using Docker-Compose, is to use one of the generated names as host for the database connection, and use a link to alias the container.

For example, with:

- A mysql container named 'db'
- `mysql_ssl_rsa_setup -v --suffix='db'` ran on the mysql container
- The generated certificate properly placed in the client container (fabric-ca, laravel, etc)

Then, add to your client container:

```
links: 
  - db:MySQL_Server_db_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate
```

And of course, use `MySQL_Server_db_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate` as the host for the database connection in your client.